# Loading and running Tensorflow model from different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

Is loading and predicting a model on different threads supported and correct in Tensorflow?

*Some background:*

When trying to load a model in thread A and then predicting it in thread B, we are given the following error message:

`ValueError: Tensor SOME_TENSOR is not an element of this graph.`

I've found this [TF GitHub thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14356), proposing to solve it by storing the graph when loading the model and using it as default when predicting. Sort of like this:

```py
# thread A
global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

...

# thread B
with graph.as_default():
    preds = model.predict(image)
```

I've tried doing that, yet I also got errors due to sessions being different and variables uninitialised:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable lstm_2_3/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/lstm_2_3/bias)
```

I started by fixing it with `keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())` yet that didn't quite work, producing wrong predictions. Instead I decided to treat session in the same way as the graph, and pass it over from when I load the model.

So the solution I have is as follows:

```py
# thread A
global graph
global sess
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
sess = K.get_session()

...

# thread B
with graph.as_default():
    try: 
        preds = model.predict(image)
    except FailedPreconditionError:
        K.set_session(sess)
        preds = model.predict(image)
```

Not gonna lie, it feels hacky. Is this the right way to handle model loading / prediction on separate threads? Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that keras/tensorflow simply aren't thread-safe, however it is possible to make it work in this case. This is hardly the correct way to fix the issue, but what helped me is changing the way I load the model.

```py
def load_threadsafe():
    model = load()  # your usual model loading
    model._make_predict_function()
    return model
```

Note the call to the protected `_make_predict_function` method, which is still hacky. The solution was shared by @fgerard on this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6109). As far as I can tell `_make_predict_function` is called internally on the first prediction, and calling it from the non-main thread causes issues. Hence the solution is to call it explicitly before any predictions are made on the thread that loads the model.

Comment: this does not work for me, unfortunately